# Shift key + click to select multiple <p> located inside different <div>

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 1</p>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 2</p>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 4</p>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 5</p>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 6</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 7</p>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 8</p>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 9</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 10</p>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 11</p>
        <p class="selectable">fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 12</p>
    </div>      
</div>
```

In above structure I want to select multiple

using shiftKey + click.

I got [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4tf9ue9/) which is similar to what I want but it did not help. so you can have a look to this also

Comment: How come the Fiddle linked is not what you want? Be more specific then.

Comment: In that link html structure is just <li> but in my case its <p> inside different <div>'s

Comment: Yeah, well.. Have you tried modifying the `HTML` structure at least or are you waiting for us to do it for you?

Comment: I tired but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".selectable", function (e) {
        var elem = $(this);
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            elem.toggleClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected {
    font-weight:bold; //Or any effect to distinguish it
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/656/

Difference between this and the reference fiddle is that when you click again on the selected item, the item is unselected.

To get the selected items:

```
$(".selected"); //this will give you an array of selected items.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made it work according to your requirements.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="div1">
    <p class="selectable">lorem</p>
    <p class="selectable">ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
    <p class="selectable">dolor</p>
    <p class="selectable">sit</p>
    <p class="selectable">amet</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>


 var $lastSelected = [],
    container     = $('.container'),
    collection    = $('.selectable');

container.on('click', '.selectable', function(e) {
    var that = $(this),
        $selected,
        direction;

    if (e.shiftKey){

        if ($lastSelected.length > 0) {

            if(that[0] == $lastSelected[0]) {
                // The user has clicked on the same item, so do nothing.
                // Remember, `that` is our event target
                // You could also make this deselect everything except for this item
                if(that.hasClass('selected')) that.removeClass('selected');
                return false;
            }           

            if(that.hasClass('selected')) that.removeClass('selected');
            else that.addClass('selected');     

            $lastSelected = that;

        } else {            
            $lastSelected = that;           
            that.addClass('lastSelected');          
            that.addClass('selected');
        }

    } else {
        // Not a shift select, so we'll just mark the target item
        $lastSelected = that;
        collection.removeClass('lastSelected selected');
        that.addClass('lastSelected selected');
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Stop offering free labor.

Comment: Hi, Sukanya
your code work fine for sibling <p> within <div> but requirement is to select <p> from different <div>s.

Comment: I think you didnt get my question here it is in detail

In above html if click on second <p> of first <div> then I press shift key and then I clicked on first <p> of third <div> then this should select all <p> 
(i.e 'fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 2' to 'fj g fjdhgdfkgd fj 7')

hope this help.